# Mongo aggregation - custom function to create field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to be able to create a field as `newField = someFunction(currentDocument)`, but it looks like this is not supported. Is it? I know I can do this within the map reduce framework, but I need to stay within the aggregation framework atm. For some edge case, I can get things to work, for instance:

```
items.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _tmp: ['$a', '$a', '$b'],
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$_tmp',
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      aab: { $sum: '$_tmp' }
    }
  },
]);
```

quite simply creates a fields that is equal to `2a+b` but that looks like overkill and inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use custom functions in your aggregate pipeline; everything must be done using the built-in operators.

That said, you can improve on what you have so far by using [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) in a `$project`:

```
items.aggregate([
    {$project: {aab: {$add: ['$a', '$a', '$b']}}}
])
```

or more expressively:

```
items.aggregate([
    {$project: {aab: {$add: [{$multiply: [2, '$a']}, '$b']}}}
])
```

Comment: I was discovering this. This is nice, and probably good enough for what I need. Thanks!